# sed command line

Tags: linux, unix, sed

Hi I need to run 'sed' command on file1.txt and have it extract all names that are in between StringA and StringB... ex: "Nickname":"bad_name", extract bad_name and then save all results too Output.txt. is this even possible or should I be looking at another command?

Comment: What are StringA and StringB? Quotation marks?

Comment: What is `StringA` and `StringB` in this example. Is it always the word after the `:` or are you actually looking for a non-changing string?

Comment: If you can post a few lines of sample input and output, I bet someone can help.  It's not clear what you're asking for.

Comment: As ghostdog74 said, you should go with awk if you need to _extract_ data. sed is used to _alter_ strings.

Comment: here's how my file looks...
{"total":31206,"page":"1","start":1,"end":31205,"userProfiles":[{"ID":"141517","Nickname":"bad_name","Gender":"Male","Age":"49","City":"Fort Worth",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without showing more sample of your file1.txt, i am assuming you have consistent data format. If it is, then use awk

```
echo '"Nickname":"bad_name"' | awk -F":" '{print $NF}'
```

For a file, just input the file name

```
awk -F":" '{print $NF}' file > output.txt
```

Otherwise, provide more sample data for us to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
dmedvinsky@home:~$ cat file1 
"Nickname":"bad_name"
"First Name":"Dmitry"
bad line
"Dog Name":"Chuppy"
another bad line

dmedvinsky@home:~$ cat file1 | sed -e '/\(.\+\)":"\(.\+\)"/!d' -e 's/"\(.\+\)":"\(.\+\)"/\2/'
bad_name
Dmitry
Chuppy
```

The first expression deletes badly formatted lines, the second one replaces the pattern with 2nd matched group -- the contents of second quotes.

Comment: the file has other user information in it so i have to isolate "Nickname":" (with the quotations) and extract bad_name with the ending string of ",
ex: "Nickname":"bad_name",
output: bad_name

the : can't be used by itself to determine where the name starts only because its not unique in the other data sets us the : as well

Comment: Well, in that case you need to change the first part of the expression (first subpattern) to `"Nickname"`.

So the command will look like:
`cat file1 | sed -e '/"Nickname":"\\(.\+\\)"/!d' -e 's/"Nickname":"\\(.\+\\)"/\1/'`

Comment: I tried the command you list and it just displayed the file content. the sed command didn't run or output anything. cat file1.txt | sed -e '/"Nickname":"\\(.\+\\)"/!d' -e 's/"Nickname":"\\(.\+\\)"/\1/'

Comment: Yep, my bad. Try this:

`cat file1 | sed -e '/"Nickname":"\\([^"]\+\\)"/!d' -e 's/.*"Nickname":"\\([^"]\+\\)".*/\1/'`

To output to file just use ` > output`.